# Prime Prime Minister and Current Prime Minister

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

***Study the table and identify the country X and the Prime Minister Y***

| Country | Number | Prime Prime Minister | Current Prime Minister |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| United Kingdom | 1 | Spencer Compton | Liz Truss |
| Israel | 2 | Levi Eshkol | Yair Lapid |
| Canada | 3 | Mackenzie Bowell | Justin Trudeau |
| India | 4 | Vishwanath Pratap Singh | Narendra Modi |
| Finland | 5 | Juho Sunila | Sanna Marin |
| X | 11 | Y | Y |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The country and Prime Minister are:

> **Australia** and **[Anthony Albanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Albanese)**

Because if the 'Number' column is represented by 'N', we need to...

> ...calculate the N<sup>th</sup> prime number (which we shall call "P"), and then find the person who was the "P<sup>th</sup>" different person to be Prime Minister of the country in question (i.e. counting each person once, rather than including non-consecutive terms separately). This makes them the *Prime Prime Minister* in question.
>
>  Using the examples given:
>
>  1<sup>st</sup> prime is 2, 2<sup>nd</sup> PM of the UK was Spencer Compton;
>  2<sup>nd</sup> prime is 3, 3<sup>rd</sup> PM of Israel was Levi Eshkol;
>  3<sup>rd</sup> prime is 5, 5<sup>th</sup> PM of Canada was Mackenzie Bowell;
>  4<sup>th</sup> prime is 7, 7<sup>th</sup> PM of India was Vishwanath Pratap Singh;
>  5<sup>th</sup> prime is 11, 11<sup>th</sup> PM of Finland was Juho Sunila.

So to fill in the gap in the table we seek...

> ...a country which has had exactly 31 Prime Ministers (as 31 is the 11<sup>th</sup> prime number). One such example (possibly the only one) is **Australia**, whose 31<sup>st</sup> *and current* Prime Minister is **Anthony Albanese**.

Comment: Wow, that was quick!